# Cosmos DB Stored Procedures, UDF & reuseable code - how do they fit together?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I've got many questions :)

I've started to use Cosmos DB (SQL API).  Loving it!

But I'm struggling to discover the best way of building and managing code.  I'm using Visual Studio.

Here's some code, and I'll base my questions on these 4 javascript functions:

```
function createYayBase(something) {
    // UDF
    return {
        pk: "Yay",
        id: "Ptr=" + something
    };
}
function createYayDoc(whatever, something) {
    // UDF
    var o = createYayBase(something);
    o.Message = whatever;
    return o;
}
function validateYayDoc(doc) {
    // UDF
    if (doc.pk !== "Yay") { throw new Error("non-Yay! :("); }
}
function processYay(val) {
    // stored procedure
    var doc = CreateYayDoc(val, "Rec");
    validateYayDoc(doc);
    ...createDocument(selflink, doc, ...);
}
```

These 4 functions are in 4 different .js files in my solution.  I would deploy the first 3 as their own user-defined function in my collection.  The last, I would deploy as a stored procedure.

My app would execute the "processYay" stored procedure to do some operations.  The UDFs are supportive.

Questions:

1. Can I call a UDF from a stored procedure directly, similar to how I've done it above in "processYay"?  Or are they only accessible as part of a query?
2. Can I call a UDF from another UDF, as I did inside "createYayDoc"?
3. Can a UDF 'throw' or is that considered a side effect in this case?

If the answers are "nope", "nope" and "nope", there seems to be another solution:  Define the functions inside the stored procedure itself.  It would work perfectly like this:

```
function processYay(val) {
    // stored procedure
    function createYayBase(something) { ... }
    function createYayDoc(whatever, something) { ... }
    function validateYayDoc(val) { ... }

    var doc = CreateYayDoc(val, "Rec");
    validateYayDoc(doc);
    ...createDocument(selflink, doc, ...);
}
```

But then...

***How can I reuse code?***

My javascript sits inside a .NET class library.  I'd love a "#include " trick :).  Do I hack something together with webpack, etc?

Or... is there some accepted approach people use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1.Can I call a UDF from a stored procedure directly, similar to how I've done it above in "processYay"? Or are they only accessible as
> part of a query?
>
> 2.Can I call a UDF from another UDF, as I did inside "createYayDoc"?
>
> 3.Can a UDF 'throw' or is that considered a side effect in this case?

The answer is nope.You could find following clear statement in the official UDF [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/programming#udf).

> User-defined functions (UDFs) are used to extend the Azure Cosmos DB
> SQL query language grammar and implement custom business logic. They
> can only be called from inside queries. They do not have access to the
> context object and are meant to be used as compute-only JavaScript.
> Therefore, UDFs can be run on secondary replicas of the Cosmos DB
> service.

I think you have some misconceptions about the `user defined function`'s application scenario. It just helps you process the result set of your query according to your custom business logic. It can not be invoked by stored procedure and can not call other methods or even manipulate the database.

Stored procedures are just JS code scripts which running on the server side.It can help you do some custom database operations ,even bulk operations. It's about special needs so that you can't think of it is an ordinary function in a complete project.

Considering reusability, you can pass some key variables in the JS code as parameters to the stored procedure.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks Jay.  Yes, my mindset was in the SQL Server world when it comes to UDFs.  As for code reuse, I meant more along the lines of reusing my helper functions in several different stored procedures.  But you answered the bulk of my question and I'll figure out a good way to structure my project.

Comment: UDF can be called from sproc -- inside sproc use something like getContext().getCollection().queryDocuments(getContext().getCollection().getSelfLink(), "select VALUE udf.MyUdf()", (err, feed) => { … })

Comment: @MichaelKoltachev Yeah..still in query sql,can't be invoked as an ordinary  function.Right?